# How to get CameraControl and CameraInfo

Tags: android, androidx, android-camerax

I'm a junior Android developer.
I'm using the last version (alpha08) of CameraX.

I am trying to set up the zoom functions and in order to do so I need CameraControl.
To get CameraControl I need an instance of my Camera -> Camera.getCameraControl() according to https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl

I don't seem to be able to get an instance of Camera. If I try to instance Camera, it asks me to implement both getCameraControl() and getCameraInfo(), whom both return null.

Could anyone explain to me how to do it please?

Here's my ApplicationClass file

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application implements CameraXConfig.Provider {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CameraXConfig getCameraXConfig() {
        return Camera2Config.defaultConfig();
    }
}
```

And my startCamera() function into my CameraActivity

```
private void startCamera() {

        CameraSelector mCameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA;

        mFlashToggle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mGalleryFAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTakePhotoFAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Point mSize = new Point();
        Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        mDisplay.getSize(mSize);
        int mWidth = mSize.x;
        int mHeight = mSize.y;

        Preview mPreview = new Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(mWidth, mHeight))
                .build();

        mPreview.setPreviewSurfaceProvider(mCameraPP.getPreviewSurfaceProvider());

        ImageCapture mImageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(mWidth, mHeight))
                .build();


        // FLASHLIGHT PART
        mFlashToggle.getBackground().setAlpha(0);

        mFlashToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean mIsActivated = true;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mIsActivated) {
                    mImageCapture.setFlashMode(ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                    mFlashToggle.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.conforme));
                    mFlashToggle.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
                    mIsActivated = false;
                } else {
                    mImageCapture.setFlashMode(ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    mFlashToggle.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    mFlashToggle.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
                    mIsActivated = true;
                }
            }
        });

        // CLICK ON TAKE PHOTO BUTTON TRIGGERS THIS
        mTakePhotoFAB.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            mDir = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "PhotosAuthentifier");
            boolean success = true;

            if (!mDir.exists()) {
                success = mDir.mkdir();
            }

            if (success) {
                File mFile = new File(mDir, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".jpg");

                mImageCapture.takePicture(mFile, command -> new Thread(command).start(),
                        new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                    // ADD PHOTO INTO FINAL TAB
                                    mListOfPhotos.add(file.getAbsolutePath());

                                    // UPDATE PREVIEW OF PHOTOS ON SCREEN
                                    mAdapter.setmListOfPhotos(mListOfPhotos);
                                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                                    if (mListOfPhotos.size() < 3) {
                                        actualNumberOfPhoto();
                                    } else {
                                        actualNumberOfPhoto();
                                    }
                                });

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(int imageCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                                String mMessage = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, mMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                assert cause != null;
                                cause.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        });
            }

        });

        // CLICK ON SEND BUTTON TRIGGERS THIS
        mSendPhotoFAB.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (mSendPhotoFAB.isClickable()) {
                mSendPhotoFAB.setClickable(false);
                AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraActivity.this);

                String mMessage = null;


                if (sIDDemande == 0) {
                    LayoutInflater mInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
                    View mDialogView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_camera_parameters, null);

                    // Parameters initialization
                    mDescriptionET = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCameraParametersDescriptionET);
                    mLanguageSpinner = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCameraSpecimenLanguageSpinner);
                    mMarkerYesButton = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCameraMarkerYesButton);
                    mMarkerNoButton = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCameraMarkerNoButton);
                    mMarkerInfoIB = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCameraMarkerInfoIB);
                    TextView mMarkerTV = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCamera15CreditTV);
                    TextView mMarkerInfoTV = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCameraMarkerInfoTV);
                    mSerialNumberET = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCameraSerialNumberET);
                    mModelNameET = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.activityCameraModelNameET);

                    mAlertDialogBuilder.setView(mDialogView);

                    // OPTIONAL PARAMETERS FORM
                    if (sIDDemande == 0) {
                        ArrayAdapter<String> mSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                        mSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                        mLanguageSpinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
                        mSpinnerAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.french));
                        mSpinnerAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.english));

                        mSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        //To make Description part scrollable
                        mDescriptionET.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
                            if (mDescriptionET.hasFocus()) {
                                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                                if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {
                                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }

                            return false;
                        });

                        // Default specimen language is defined according to app language
                        String mLanguage = LocaleHelper.getLanguage(this).getString(LocaleHelper.SELECTED_LANGUAGE, null);

                        if (mLanguage != null) {
                            if (mLanguage.equals("fr")) {
                                mLanguageSpinner.setSelection(0);
                            } else if (mLanguage.equals("en")) {
                                mLanguageSpinner.setSelection(1);
                            }
                        }

                        mMarkerInfoIB.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                            if (!mMarkerInfoIsClicked) {
                                mMarkerInfoTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mMarkerInfoIsClicked = true;
                            } else {
                                mMarkerInfoTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mMarkerInfoIsClicked = false;
                            }
                        });

                        mMarkerNoButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.authentifier));
                        mMarkerYesButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));

                        mMarkerYesButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                            if (!mMarkerYesClicked) {
                                mMarkerYesButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.authentifier));
                                mMarkerNoButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
                                mMarkerTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mMarkerYesClicked = true;
                            }
                        });

                        mMarkerNoButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                            if (mMarkerYesClicked) {
                                mMarkerNoButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.authentifier));
                                mMarkerYesButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
                                mMarkerTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mMarkerYesClicked = false;
                            }
                        });

                        if (mAlertDialog != null) {
                            Objects.requireNonNull(mAlertDialog.getWindow()).setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (sIDDemande != 0) {
                    mMessage = getResources().getString(R.string.validationBeforePursue);
                }

                mAlertDialogBuilder
                        .setTitle(R.string.activityCameraParametersTitle)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setMessage(mMessage)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, (dialog, which) -> {
                            ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(which).setClickable(false);
                            dialog.dismiss();

                            if (sIDDemande != 0) {
                                new AsyncTaskSendComplementaryPhotos(sCameraActivity, sCameraActivity.getApplicationContext()).execute();
                            } else {
                                if (mDescriptionET.getText() != null && !mDescriptionET.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    mMapApplication.put(ConstantsClass.APPLICATION_DESCRIPTION, mDescriptionET.getText().toString());
                                }

                                if (mSerialNumberET.getText() != null && !mSerialNumberET.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    mMapApplication.put(ConstantsClass.SERIAL_NUMBER, mSerialNumberET.getText().toString());
                                }

                                if (mModelNameET.getText() != null && !mModelNameET.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    mMapApplication.put(ConstantsClass.MODEL_NAME, mModelNameET.getText().toString());
                                }

                                String mSpinnerValue = mLanguageSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                                if (mSpinnerValue.equals("French")) {
                                    mSpinnerValue = "Français";
                                }

                                if (mSpinnerValue.equals("English")) {
                                    mSpinnerValue = "Anglais";
                                }

                                mMapApplication.put(ConstantsClass.LANGUAGE_SPECIMEN, mSpinnerValue);

                                if (mMarkerYesClicked) {
                                    mMapApplication.put(ConstantsClass.MARKER, "OUI");
                                } else {
                                    mMapApplication.put(ConstantsClass.MARKER, "NON");
                                }

                                new AsyncTaskSendData(sCameraActivity).execute();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            mSendPhotoFAB.setClickable(true);
                        });

                mAlertDialog = mAlertDialogBuilder.create();

                mAlertDialog.show();
            } else {
                Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.waitingMessageBeforeParameters), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                View mToastView = mToast.getView();

                mToastView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.authentifier));
                mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                mToast.show();
            }
        });

        // CLICK ON GALLERY BUTTON TRIGGERS THIS
        mGalleryFAB.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            checkPermissions();

            if (mPermission) {
                Intent mIntentGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                mIntentGallery.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(mIntentGallery, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }

        });

        ImageAnalysis mAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();

        mCameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                mCameraProvider = mCameraProviderFuture.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            assert mCameraProvider != null;
            mCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(sCameraActivity, mCameraSelector, mPreview, mAnalysis, mImageCapture);
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting `androidx.camera.core.Camera` instance as a result of call `mCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(sCameraActivity, mCameraSelector, mPreview, mAnalysis, mImageCapture);` at the end of your method.

**Example** :

```
private Camera camera;

camera = mCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(sCameraActivity, mCameraSelector, mPreview, mAnalysis, mImageCapture);
```

Then, when you need to acces to the CameraControl or CameraInfo of the Camera just use:

```
camera.getCameraControl()
camera.getCameraInfo()
```

Comment: @lena I believe this is a correct answer. You might want to accept then for it to appear in search as the one with accepted answer. Others can make use of it then...